# Canonical Function in Linq to Entities not working

Tags: c#, sql, linq

Trying to run this query in my code:

```
var rslt = ent.AppointmentDiaries.Where(s => s.DateTimeScheduled >=
                fromDate && EntityFunctions.AddMinutes(
                s.DateTimeScheduled, s.AppointmentLength) <= toDate);
```

It keeps breaking up with:

```
An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime] AddMinutes(System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime], System.Nullable`1[System.Int32])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
```

using entityframework 6.1.0 ...

I know about canonical gunctions, so I would expect EntityFunctions.AddMinutes to work with codefirst queries...

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `EntityFunctions` has become `DbFunctions`.

Comment: much obliged..How were we supposed to know that? why not remove the old one..*confused*. Thanks mate this worked just fine. You should have posted it as an answer so I can give you a thumbs up :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Entity Framework 6 `EntityFunctions` has been replaced by `DbFunctions`. The old class is now marked as obsolete and will disappear in the future.

I must admit that it's not directly obvious when you google for release notes. There is however a blog describing how to
[upgrade to EF6](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/upgradeef6) where this change is mentioned.

Comment: Its really not obvious

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's just like @Gert said. Here is the code for it:

```
var rslt = ent.tbl_Appoiment_Diary.Where(s => s.DateTimeScheduled >= fromDate && DbFunctions.AddMinutes(s.DateTimeScheduled, s.AppointmentLenght) <= toDate);
```

Hope this helps. Thx again for the info @Gert! Cheers.